# Function $\int_0^1 x^{a}(1-x)^{n}~dx$ used for Gamma Function

Tags: real-analysis, mathematical-physics

I was reading a historical note on Euler and found that below given function is used to find Gamma Function:

> $$ \int_0^1 x^{a}(1-x)^{n} dx .$$

And I could not understand that why this function is said to be very famous as being used by Wallis, Newton and Sterling.

> How and why people choose this function?

Comment: Are you sure the limits are from $0$ to $\infty$ not $0$ to $1$?

Comment: You are  correct its from 0 to 1

Comment: It is known as the beta function.

Comment: How people came up with this function?